# Does the ForEach loop allow using break and continue?

Tags: javascript

Does the `ForEach` loop allow us to use `break` and `continue`?

I've tried using both but I received an error:

```
Illegal break/continue statement
```

If it does allow, how do I use them?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, it doesn't, because you pass a callback as a return, which is executed as an ordinary function.

Let me be clear:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr.forEach(function(i) {
    console.log(i);
});

// is like

var cb = function(i) {
    console.log(i);
    // would "break" here do anything?
    // would "continue" here do anything?
    // of course not.
}

for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    cb(arr[j]);
}
```

**All forEach does is call a real, actual *function* you give to it repeatedly, ignore how it exits, then calls it again on the next element.**

In that callback function if you return it will incidentally work like `continue` in the case of `forEach`. Because the rest of the function won't execute that time, and it will be called again. There is no analogue of `break.`

Ruby supports this flexibility, using blocks/procs instead of methods/lambdas.

Per [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> Note : There is no way to stop or break a forEach loop. The solution is to use Array.every or Array.some. See example below.

`every` and `some` are exactly like `forEach`, except they pay attention to the return value of the callback. `every` will break on a falsey value and `some` will break on a truthy value, since they shortcircuit. They are exactly analogous to `&&` and `||`. `&&` tests whether *every* expression is truthy, `||` tests for whether *some* is, which should help you remember how short-circuiting works with `every` and `some`. When in doubt, try it.

Comment: continue goes to the next iteration. Is the same with return?

Comment: @user3450695 continue is illegal and throws an error.

Comment: which one skips the remaining "stuff" in the block and goes to the next iteration?

Answer (score 10):

As already answered, you cannot use `continue` or `break` inside a JavaScript `Array.prototype.forEach` loop. However, there are other options:

### Option 1

Use the jQuery `.each()` function ([Reference](https://api.jquery.com/each/)).

Simply `return true` to *continue*, or `return false` to *break* the loop.

### Option 2

Just use `return` to *continue* or `throw new Error()` to *break*. I don't necessarily recommend doing it this way, but it's interesting to know that this is possible.

```
try {
    [1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(function(i) {

        if (i === 2) {
            return; // continue
        }

        if (i === 3) {
            throw new Error(); // break
        }

        console.log(i);
    });
}
catch (e) {
}
```

The expected result is just `1`